# Can anyone identify this capacitor?

Tags: laptop, capacitor

I need to replace this capacitor on an Acer E5-571 Laptop motherboard.

I'm trying to work out the ratings.  I am no expert, but know enough to resolder a new capacitor.

From what I have worked out, this is 68uf, but what is the voltage?  Is that 25V, with a tolerance of 3% (the "H"), or does the H indicate something else?

Diameter is 8mm approx

If anyone could point me to an equivalent on ebay?

[image: laptop capacitor]

Comment: A tolerance of 3% is utterly ridiculous to expect out of an electrolytic capacitor like that, so I'm quite sure that is not correct. It may be 25V though, I don't remember how to read those types of capacitors.

Comment: How tall is the removed capacitor?

Answer (score 2):

I saw your post on superuser.com. I guess these should be of the same type with 68uF, 25V, Tolerance +-20%

https://www.ebay.com/itm/112718718797
https://www.ebay.com/itm/401463176944
https://www.ebay.com/itm/222318126020

Please check the dimensions before you buy!

Comment: Thanks for those ebay links.  But is it 100% 25V??  See this which says H could represent 50V  https://forum.digikey.com/t/smt-electrolytic-capacitor-with-no-voltage-rating/974

Comment: @Pingers H represents 50 V only if there aren't digits, such as 25, for the voltage. Can you tell us what part of the circuitry it comes from? I think the only circuitry that might need anything over 25 V would be the display backlight, assuming the laptop doesn't have a Firewire connector.

Answer (score 0):

I found the capacitor came from the part of the board labelled PC807, near the CPU, which when I looked it up on the schematic shows it is 68uf and 25V (see attached)

Found some other capacitors on an old Samsung board which have the same spec and are the same size, so problem solved.

[image: capacitor identified on schematic 68uf 25v]

Thanks for all your input.